# CredStore Perform Query error

Tags: ios, xcode9

I am running into an issue while doing API calls to my apps backend, every connection now prompts with

```
CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
    atyp = http;
    class = inet;
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    ptcl = http;
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    srvr = "myappsurl.com";
    sync = syna;
}
```

I am a little lost as I am not sure what is causing this, or what CredStore even does. 
What purpose does CredStore serve in iOS?

Comment: I am having the same log in the simulator using iOS 11 + Xcode beta 6. I hope this is just because of the beta

Comment: did you never find a solution to this?

Comment: @swalkner not yet, still trying to find out more.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any news?

Comment: Are you playing a video?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did anyone find any explanation ?

Comment: @DanielStorm No, I am doing API requests to a backend service, with a standard json response.

Comment: @AnthonyTaylor weird. I don’t get this on JSON calls. AVPlayer HLS stream causes this for me.

Comment: Im facing this error too. This happens to me when i scroll UICollectionView vertically. I'm also using AVPlayer under Collection cells.

Comment: This line audioAsset = AVURLAsset.init(url: URL(string: pAudioUrl!)!) causes this error. Wondering why its throwing this error as audios are running fine here.

Comment: The same problem : CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
    class = inet;
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    sync = syna;
}

Comment: any updates? I'm getting the same trying to play and .mp4 file `player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)`

Comment: Any updates? I faced this error too.

Comment: I am facing same issue. Any solution for this?

Comment: I'm getting this error too. I'm using AVPlayer from AVFoundation

Comment: I'm getting this every time I play a video with [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:myhttpsurl]

Comment: Any solution for above ? facing same problem while multiple time play video?

Comment: same problem here but when using flutter :(

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This error occurs when trying to retrieve an `URLCredential` from `URLCredentialStorage` for an unknown `URLProtectionSpace`.
e.g.

```
let protectionSpace = URLProtectionSpace.init(host: host, 
                                              port: port, 
                                              protocol: "http", 
                                              realm: nil, 
                                              authenticationMethod: nil)

var credential: URLCredential? = URLCredentialStorage.shared.defaultCredential(for: protectionSpace)
```

produces

```
CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
    class = inet;
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    ptcl = http;
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    srvr = host;
    sync = syna;
}
```

Give it a credential for the protection space:

```
let userCredential = URLCredential(user: user, 
                                   password: password, 
                                   persistence: .permanent)

URLCredentialStorage.shared.setDefaultCredential(userCredential, for: protectionSpace)
```

and the error goes away next time you try to retrieve the credential.

> I am a little lost as I am not sure what is causing this, or what
>   CredStore even does. What purpose does CredStore serve in iOS?

Credential storage on iOS allows users to securely store certificate-based or password-based credentials on the device either temporarily or permanently to the keychain.

I suspect that you have some sort of authentication on your backend server and that server is requesting an authentication challenge to your app (for which no credential exists).

It can probably be safely ignored as returning nil from the `URLCredentialStorage` is a valid response

Comment: How would you go about created a protection space?

Comment: @Brett can you please provide information for protectionSpace?

Comment: @Brett my fault just thought the first part was producing the error I have. after editing the Answer I can upvote it

Comment: how to use in Moya and Alamofire?

Comment: I also have this issue when using alamofire https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50342214/how-to-upload-an-image-using-alamofire-with-basic-authentication ,  i don't know where to put userCredential in Alamofire :(

Comment: @Brett, I am also facing this issue when calling Twilio API through AFNetwrking. Any suggestions, what to search in order to grab the issue with AFNetworking?

Answer (score 14):

I'm not sure why do we get this error when perform requests with Alamofire, but if you do API requests with some token in HTTP headers, you maybe don't need credentials store at all. So we can disable it for our request:

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = ourHeaders
// disable default credential store
configuration.urlCredentialStorage = nil

let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
...
```

No errors after such change.

Answer (score 6):

This same issue happens to me and I found that if your API URL does not contain a "/" at the end of URL then iOS does not send "Authorization" value to the server. Due to which you will see a message like posted in question in the console.

So Simply add "/" at the end of URL

```
https://example.com/api/devices/
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me, but why is that?

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I was not initialising Stripe SDK with API key.

```
        STPPaymentConfiguration.shared().publishableKey = publishableKey
```

In case of any Stripe operation, we can print the error log, its easy to understand.

```
        print(error.debugDescription)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is transport error, let's add transport permission like this in plist file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

**Be careful** as that enables connection to any server from your app. Read more on App Transport Security before proceeding. See comment by @kezi

Comment: I don't know why this gets downvotes, this solution helped me! I have had problems with audiostream via FRadioPlayer https://github.com/fethica/FRadioPlayer

Comment: @caffeinum Because this removes any security what so ever. This is not an error on the part of the software. This is added in to give a barrier of protection to your app. This answer says nothing about that or what arbitrary loads means.

Comment: Apple's app review will probably flag this and you'll be asked why your app needs to connect to arbitrary hosts. They may reject the app if they don't like your answer. It's much better to add a key for the specific hostname you're trying to connect to.

Answer (score 2):

I edited the String that contains the URL to fix this issue:

```
var myUrl = "http://myurl.com"
myUrl = myUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed)!

let url = URL(string: myUrl)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you get this error, when using AVPlayer, just call .play() on main thread

Comment: With AVPlayer - I'm not calling play but loading assets and then call pause, but still got this warning.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of me getting this error was due to me accidentally using two spaces between the "Bearer" and access token in my Authorization header.

Incorrect:

```
request.setValue("Bearer  \(accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

Correct:

```
request.setValue("Bearer \(accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

Simple mistake, but it took a while to find it.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I had this error, and fought with it for a long time (years) when interacting with my Ruby on Rails app.

I had default credentials set up as described in the accepted answer, but still got the error, and have been relying on a didReceiveChallenge response to supply the credentials - fortunately that worked as a work around.

But! I've just found the solution!

I was working on a hunch that that the protectedSpace fields did not match the Authorization challenge from the Ruby on Rails server - and I looked into the realm field, which seemed to be the only one that was being left undefined.

I started by printing out the server response headers, and although I was able to examine these, they did not include the WWW-Authorization field that would have included the realm field.

I thought this was maybe because my Rails app wasn't specifying the realm, so I started looking at the Rails side of things.

I found I could specify the realm in the call to,

```
authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic
```

...which I am using for HTTP Basic authentication.

I wasn't specifying a realm already, so added one,

```
authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic("My Rails App")
```

I then added the corresponding string to the protectionSpace,

```
NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace =
    [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc] initWithHost:@"myrailsapp.com"
        port:443
        protocol:NSURLProtectionSpaceHTTPS
        realm:@"My Rails App"
        authenticationMethod:NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic];
```

Voila!  That worked, and I no longer get the,

```
CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300
```

Even after specifying the realm in the Rails app, I still don't see it passed in the HTTP header, I don't know why, but at least it works.

Comment: Very glad to found your answer, it was really freaking me out.

Answer (score 0):

The error may also be caused by a Content Security Policy (CSP) that may be too restrictive. In our case, we needed a CSP that is more or less completely open and allows everything. Keep in mind that opening the CSP can be a great security issue (depending on what exactly you're doing in the app).

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue when I tried to open a http-page inside a web-view. But this page contained an popup which was opened first.

When backend team removed this popup everything became OK.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was base64 encoding of an image that was being sent with a rest call

I had previously used

```
let strBase64 = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
```

But 50% of the time I would get the error above.

I used the following instead which solved my problem...

```
 let strBase64 = imageData.base64EncodedString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with Twitter sign in. Turned out I used the the wrong API key.

Answer (score 0):

I remove `.cURLDescription`
on

```
AF.request(url)
```

and that log is gone

Answer (score 0):

When working with the Stripe IOS SDK, I found that I should have added the publishable key from stripe.

This is set in AppDelegate, as found in https://stripe.com/docs/development/quickstart, step 2.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        StripeAPI.defaultPublishableKey = "pk_test_....."
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    let credentialData = "\(user):\(password)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
    let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: params,encoding: URLEncoding.default,headers: headers)
                .responseJSON{
            response in
            guard let value =  response.result.value else {return}
                    print(value)
     }
```