# "CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching cred." Error when opening Vimeo with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, vimeo-api, vimeo-player, vimeo-ios

I am trying to play a Vimeo video on my swift app on a subview using a subclass of AVPlayer. Even though there is no need for credentials or logging into Vimeo to see this particular video, when I try to set up the video I get the following error:

```
CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
   class = inet;
   "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
   "r_Attributes" = 1;
   sync = syna;
}
```

My code is pretty straightforward after setting the player on a UIView:

```
player.set(AVURLAsset(url: URL(string: videoURLString)!))
player.play()
```

Any ideas on what might be going wrong, or how to simply play a Vimeo video on a subview in my VC?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CredStore Perform Query error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099940/credstore-perform-query-error)

Comment: Getting this warning from an AVAsset when loading it async, from *my* https server.

Answer (score 0):

The technical answer is at this duplicate question - [CredStore Perform Query error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099940/credstore-perform-query-error)
I have the same problem with Google Drive - both on 'share to anyone with the link' and also 'public'.  It seems '''public''' services still do like to ask for credentials because the provider benefits in some way.  We need to manage that even though we are using public services.