# CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds. Error=-25300

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

Error:

```
CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
    class = inet;
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    sync = syna;
}
```

I have downloaded VGPlayerExample(https://github.com/VeinGuo/VGPlayer) pod when I run that sample application it's playing all videos but when I add my URL(http://sampledomain/some/playlist.m3u8) it's not playing and showing above-mentioned error. Can anyone pls suggest a possible solution to this issue.

Comment: I'm facing this too. Any fix?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48961852/2875219 this answer helped me. You can try other options

Comment: i fixed this by giving type HTTPHeaders  e.g.  let header: HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "access_token") as! String)"