# AVPlayer Stuck in play : We have added AVPlayer in horizontal collection view but its stuck some time while play in multiple time

Tags: ios, iphone, streaming, avplayer, m3u8

```
self.avPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mediaURL]];
```

above line giving error :

```
CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
    class = inet;
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    sync = syna;
}
```

and some time stuck and some time play.

I checked below link but not helpful: 
[CredStore Perform Query error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099940/credstore-perform-query-error)

Please suggest any solution/workaround for it.

Note: this issue not generating in simulator its coming only in device.

Thanks in Advance.