# URLSession POST call

Tags: swift, urlsession

I don't have much experience with URLSession, but I'm trying to do a POST call, and I keep getting two different errors.

Here is my function:

```
func test() {
    let parameters = ["username": "myUsername", "password": "myPassword"]
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://example.com:443/Auth/") else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else { return }
    request.httpBody = httpBody

    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(json)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

And here are the errors that I'm running into:

This first one has a stack overflow link: [CredStore Perform Query error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099940/credstore-perform-query-error). I added the code that they said to add, but I ended up having the same errors.

```
CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query = {
    class = inet;
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    ptcl = htps;
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    sdmn = "/Auth/";
    srvr = "example.com";
    sync = syna; 
}
```

The next error that I get is:

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600000b94180> { URL: https://example.com:443/Auth/ } { Status Code: 401, Headers {
"Content-Length" =     (
    31
);
"Content-Type" =     (
    "text/plain"
);
Date =     (
    "Mon, 24 Sep 2018 23:16:45 GMT"
);
"Www-Authenticate" =     (
    "Basic realm=\"/Auth/\""
);
} }
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

I'm getting a 401 Unauthorized error. The only reason I can see it giving me 401 is that it isn't reading in the username/password correctly? I'm not 100% sure if the header titles "username" and "password" are correct. The actual username and password are definitely correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people that run into this problem:

I figured out what was wrong:

```
func test() {
    let username = "myUsername"
    let password = "myPassword"
    let loginString = String(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
    let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString()

    let url = URL(string: "https://example.com:443/Auth/")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(json)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

My username and password were being sent in as plain text. Had to encode my credentials to base64.