# Why Alamofire throws a CredStore error on post request?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, swift, authentication, alamofire

I m working on an iOS project with swift and Alamofire and I m getting a weird message when I m trying tot do post a request. The weird part is that for get request is working fine.

```
CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
class = inet;
"m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
ptcl = htps;
"r_Attributes" = 1;
sdmn = Application;
srvr = "www.***.com";
sync = syna;}
```

I m not sure what it means.

```
Alamofire.request(
       path,
       method: .post
      ).responseJSON { response in

                switch response.result {
                    case .success(let data):
                        let json = JSON(data)
                        print(json)
                       
                    case .failure(let err):
                        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                        print(err)
                    }

                }
```

We are using Ruby on Rails for the backend and the returned json is always:

```
{ "error" : "" }
```

Also in the Rails rest controller we are using `before_action :authenticate_user!`. If I remove this service from the controller is working fine but we need it. Also I've tried with the local server and with the server on a remote host but same results.

I also found this post that talks about the same error [CredStore Perform Query error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099940/credstore-perform-query-error) but we dont use username and password authentication for this app.

Another approach was to set the cookies from the login manually with Alamofire SessionManager but it did not helped.

```
lazy var sessionManager: SessionManager = {
        
            let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies
            let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = HTTPCookie.requestHeaderFields(with: cookies ?? [])
            configuration.urlCredentialStorage = nil

            let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
               
            return manager
    }()
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is produced by the operating system checking to see if there are any credentials associated with your domain, as Alamofire implements the relevant `URLSession` delegate method, and does not affect request completion. You can ignore it.

Comment: Not really, I can't igonre this problem because the response body is not what I need. The server returns {error: ""}, not the json I need. Also the status code is 401.

Comment: If you actually need to use a credential, use the `authenticate()` method with the appropriate credentials, or add the appropriate header.